# Super Meat Boy - could someone with all bandages provide overworld screenshots?

Tags: super-meat-boy

I would like some help homing in on the last few bandages I need, but I don't want a step-by-step guide for every bandage. I just want to compare my overworld screen with someone who has all 100 bandages, so I know which worlds I need to explore and which warp zones to get.

Comment: Which platform (PC or Xbox)?

Comment: I believe the levels and the bandages are the same on both PC and XBox360 platforms. However, the extra characters are different between them. (I might be wrong, though)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a text-only list of which levels have bandages or warp zones:

http://www.diygamer.com/2010/10/super-meat-boy-bandage-warp-zone-guide/

Not exactly what you asked (because you asked for screenshots), but it is close enough.

If someone wants a comprehensive guide, including screenshots showing the position of each bandage in each level, check this series of posts (spoiler warning! the following links spoil all the fun!):
[World 1](http://www.xblafans.com/super-meat-boy-bandage-guide-world-one-3183.html), 
[World 2](http://www.xblafans.com/super-meat-boy-bandage-guide-world-two-3316.html), 
[World 3](http://www.xblafans.com/super-meat-boy-bandage-guide-world-three-3470.html), 
[World 4](http://www.xblafans.com/super-meat-boy-bandage-guide-world-four-3632.html), 
[World 5](http://www.xblafans.com/super-meat-boy-bandage-guide-world-five-3962.html).

Comment: This is more useful than screenshots anyway, screenshots wouldn't show which Warp Zones contain bandages or how many.

Comment: Actually, all warp zones contain either 2 bandages, or an unlockable character.